# Compare two list of list of dictionaries and extract the required list from 2nd section?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two different sets of list of list of dictionaries which comprises of unique keys like dept & aoi.

Set1:

```
 [{'dept':'maths','aoi':'linear_algebra','name':'tom'},
  {'dept':'maths','aoi':'linear_algebra','name':'sam'}, 
  {'dept':'maths','aoi':'linear_algebra','name':'tim'}]
```

set2:

```
[[{'dept':'maths','sec':'a','aoi':'linear_algebra','class':'IX'},
  {'dept':'maths','sec':'a','aoi':'linear_algebra','class':'X'}, 
  {'dept':'maths','sec':'b','aoi':'linear_algebra','class':'XI'}],
 [{'dept':'maths','sec':'a','aoi':'trigonometry','class':'VII'},
  {'dept':'maths','sec':'c','aoi':'trigonometry','class':'VIII'}, 
  {'dept':'maths','sec':'b','aoi':'trigonometry','class':'VI'}]]
```

How can I compare and extract the list from set-2 with respect to set-1 based on the keys "dept" & "aoi", So that the result is,

```
  [{'dept':'maths','sec':'a','aoi':'linear_algebra','class':'IX'},
  {'dept':'maths','sec':'a','aoi':'linear_algebra','class':'X'}, 
  {'dept':'maths','sec':'b','aoi':'linear_algebra','class':'XI'}]
```

Comment: What language? Please tag along with the question.

Comment: Based on what you have provided, it appears that the only way you would be able to extract those specific dictionaries would be to use `depth` and `aoi` as your search targets as it appears `name` has no significance to the search.